# Monitor GPU usage of a remote machine

Tags: gpu, monitoring, remote-server

I would like to regularly monitor the memory and utilization of GPU (present in nvidia-smi output) in a remote machine. I am planning to set a cronjob that runs every hour in my machine. The job should check the GPU status of a list of remote machines and log them. Is it possible to do this? i.e., can I somehow check the memory and utilization remotely? If so, how do I do that?

I would prefer python to do this.